# From Runge-Kutta Butcher tableau to general linear methods matrices?

Tags: numerics, ode, runge-kutta

I am trying to understand how the relationship between Butcher tables for Runge-Kutta methods and their generalization to general linear methods matrices (by Butcher also).

- **Runge-Kutta methods** can be specified by the nodes $c_i$, the weights $b_j$ and the coefficients $a_{ij}$ under the form of Butcher tables (see Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)) (as well as $b_j^*$ for adaptive methods)
- **General linear methods** can be specified with a table of four matrices $A$, $B$, $V$, $U$ (see Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_methods))

Since Runge-Kutta methods can be seen as a subclass of general linear methods, I am wondering how $c_i$, $b_j$, $b_j^*$, $a_{ij}$ relate to $A$, $B$, $V$, $U$ (in particular $c_i$) (how to express the first ones in terms of the second ones, and vice-versa).

Comment: You can inspect element on Wikipedia and copy LaTeX code for the various equations into your post so it is more self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

Given a Runge-Kutta method with the tableau

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
c & A \\ \hline
& b^T
\end{array}
= \begin{array}{c|ccc}
c_1 & a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,s} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_s & a_{s,1} & \dots & a_{s,s} \\ \hline
& b_1 & \dots & b_s
\end{array}
$$

it is equivalent to a GLM with the tableau

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
c & A & U \\ \hline
& B & V
\end{array}
= \begin{array}{c|c|c}
c & A & e \\ \hline
& b^T & 1
\end{array}
= \begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
c_1 & a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,s} & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_s & a_{s,1} & \dots & a_{s,s} & 1 \\ \hline
& b_{1} & \dots & b_{s} & 1
\end{array}
$$

The Taylor series weights for the external stages are

$$
W = [q_0, q_1, \dots, q_k] = [1, 0, \dots, 0]
$$

since $y_1^{[n]} = y_n$.
Note that for a GLM with stage order one, $c = A e + U q_1$.
This is discussed in "[General Linear Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470522165)" section 2, for example.

Embedded methods for GLMs are not as standardized as they are for Runge-Kutta schemes.

Comment: So does that mean that a GLM is not entirely specified by $A$, $U$, $B$, $V$ and need $c$ on top of that?

Comment: Technically, $A, B, U, V, W, c$ are all needed to specify a GLM. Essentially every practical GLM has a stage order of at least one, though, which allows $c$ to be deduced from the other coefficients.

Comment: What about $b_{j}^{*}$ in adaptive RK methods? How does it relate to $A$, $U$, $B$, $V$, $c$?